# Build APK from splited APK generated with Instant Run

Tags: android, apk, instant-run

I deleted my project from the filesystem, i cant recover it, neither with the recyclebin nor with a program to recover deleted files. BTW i have the app installed in the phone, but when i recover the APK i get the next files:

-Folder "lib" empty.

-base.apk

-split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk

-split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk (i have 10 like this one only changing the number)

I have the way to get the source code of any apk, but when i try that process on the base.apk, i get none of my code, instead, i get 2 packages "com.android.tools.fd.common" and "com.android.tools.fd.runtime" with classes i never wrote.

I think i have that split because i was running my app with "Instant Run" activated without me noticing it.

Is there a way to join all this APKs to get the final one running on my phone?

Pd: I also tried the "Local History" solution and didnt work.

Comment: try icare recovery tool

Comment: Use APKTool which will decompile your app. Navigate to your java files in the decompiled app folder and you can use them again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, none of the programs you guys proposed work with my problem, i solved it decompiling every slice till i found the last change i have made on the code. Thank you for all your time!

Comment: Can you share which index it was? Was it your split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk as well? It's very interesting to me that there is little documentation on these split packages.